# How to get Country name by its coordinates using qml?

Tags: qt, qml, coordinates, reverse-geocoding, qt-quick

I tried with Geocodemodel reversing process but after calling it 2-3 times or giving timer then only its giving correct value that to its working sometimes only.

Plugin {
id: mapPlugin
name: "osm"
}

```
GeocodeModel {
    id: geocodeModel
    plugin: mapPlugin
    autoUpdate: false
}
function _country()
{
    geocodeModel.query = coordinates.text
    geocodeModel.update()
    if(geocodeModel.count > 0)
    {
        console.log("Name of the Country "+geocodeModel.get(0).address.country)
        return geocodeModel.get(0).address.country;

    }
}
```

For first time call,its showing this error QCoreApplication::postEvent: Unexpected null receiver how to remove this error and fetch country name by first call itself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer instead calling geocodemodel in function we can do below thing. will get country name when count is incremented but it takes bit time.

```
GeocodeModel {
        id: geocodeModel;
        plugin: mapPlugin;
        autoUpdate: false;
        onLocationsChanged:      
        {
            if( count > 0 )
            
                var country=geocodeModel.get(0).address.country;
                console.log("Country ="+country);
            }
        }
    }
    function _country()
    {
        geocodeModel.query = dstId.text
        geocodeModel.update()

    }
```