QGeoLocation Seeting QGeoCoordinate coordinate problem
I am using this code to a set a QGeoAddress Address of a QGeoLocation Loacation , problem is when I try to retreive the coordinate of the location its always invalid with a value nan
#include <QGeoLocation>
#include <QGeoAddress>
#include <QGeoCoordinate>
bool LocationInterface::setLocationCountry(const QString &country , const QString& city)
{
    QGeoAddress address;
    QGeoLocation Location;
    QGeoCoordinate geo_coordinate
    address.setCountry(country);
    address.setCity(city);
    Location.setAddress(address);
    geo_coordinate.setLatitude(Location.coordinate().latitude());
    geo_coordinate.setLongitude(Location.coordinate().longitude());
    if(!geo_coordinate.isValid()){

        return false;
    }
    setLatitude(Location.coordinate().latitude()); // Setter of a latitude param
    setLongitude(Location.coordinate().longitude()); // setter of a longitude param
    return true;
}


this seems abetter solution with qml https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71436207/how-to-get-country-name-by-its-coordinates-using-qml
